# Using Annotations in Java at the Class Level for Every Field

Tags: java, annotations

I have a custom annotation that I currently have annotated on every field. This is fine, but not super clean. I want to give the ability to put this annotation on the class to then automatically annotate every field.

```
@Target(value = {ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAnnotation {

    boolean searchable() default true;

    String attribute() default "";
}

// Current Class
@Entity
@Table(name = "TESTER")
public class Tester () {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @TestAnnotation 
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @TestAnnotation 
    @Column(name = "COL_1", nullable = false)
    private String col1;

    @TestAnnotation 
    @Column(name = "COL_2", nullable = false)
    private String col2;

    @TestAnnotation 
    @Column(name = "COL_3", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String col3;

    @TestAnnotation 
    @Column(name = "COL_4", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String col4;
}
```

---

```
// Expectation
@Entity
@TestAnnotation 
@Table(name = "TESTER")
public class Tester () {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "COL_1", nullable = false)
    private String col1;

    @Column(name = "COL_2", nullable = false)
    private String col2;

    @Column(name = "COL_3", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String col3;

    @Column(name = "COL_4", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String col4;
}
```

Comment: You must be processing that annotation somewhere for each field right. If that's the case, can you annotate your class, and then use reflection to get all fields and process them using your existing logic?

Comment: I am processing the annotation and setting the fields inside the annotation itself, which is working for each field. But trying to do the same with the class level I cannot put multiple values into the annotation because it's being overridden.

Comment: I guess I can change my logic so that I'm storing the values somewhere outside of the annotation for the class level manipulation.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?